# Python Installing Cython & Numba but no vcvarsall.bat despite Visual C++ 2010

Tags: python, cython, python-3.4, numba

I use Python 3.4

I try to install Cython and Numba but keep getting "Unable to find vcvarsall.bat".

I googled for the solution and found that I need Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 installed (for Python 3.4).

So I installed it.

And tried installing Cython and Numba ---> fail.

And then they say I must type "SET VS90COMNTOOLS=%VS100COMNTOOLS%" in the command prompt, which I did, like C:\Users\Dorky>set vs90comntools=%vs100comntools%.

And tried installing Cython and Numba again ---> fail.

Not enough with that, I also went to the environment variables to set this VS90 to VS100 thing manually.

And tried installing Cython and Numba again ---> fail.

So how exactly can I solve this special "Unable to find vcvarsall.bat" problem?

What the heck is so special with this vcvarsall.bat that the user must install Microsoft's programs in order to use it?

Why not just extract out this vcvarsall.bat file as an independent file and then just copy&paste it to any file or directory that needs and not bother with the rest of the software package?

Why not the Python team just extract out this vcvarsall.bat and incorporate it into its Python packages so whenever a user installs Python, he/she will also install vcvarsall.bat along the way and then Python would also know where to look for this file in case needing to install Cython or Numba or any other?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the python.org version of Python, there's a much easier way to go about things - grab the packages you're interested in from Christoph Gohlke's [Python Extension Packages for Windows](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) repository. He has a very large selection of mainly scientific computing-based Python modules, including [`Cython`](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#cython) and [`numba`](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numba) (you'll need [`numpy`](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy) - compiled with Intel's [MKL](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-mkl) - and [`llvmlite`](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#llvmlite) - which requires [this](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784) - as well). Everything is precompiled into `.whl` packages that can be installed with an up-to-date version of [`pip`](https://pip.pypa.io/). Most modules are kept updated with the latest versions on [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org) or other repositories.

This is definitely my go-to site for installing packages on Windows, and if what I'm looking for isn't there, then I'll install via `pip` or the package source.

Comment: I can do installation without using pip.

Comment: @Dorky what do you mean? Installation of what?

Comment: I mean I can do installation of modules without using pip, just by going to the command prompt and type cd c:\users\....>python setup.py install. It's just trying to install Cython and Numba that I meet with vcvarsall.bat error.

Comment: @Dorky just because you *can* install modules via `python setup.py install`, doesn't mean you *should*. Read up on `pip` and what it can do. Besides, if you want to use Gohlke's modules, you'll *need* to have `pip` installed. Tell me, which is easier: downloading a `.tar.gz` file, unzipping it, entering the directory, then running `setup.py`, or just entering a single command `pip install MyPackage`, which will reverse itself if it doesn't work, can be uninstalled at any time, and remembers which version is installed? Yes, there are times when you need to install from source, but not many.

Comment: @Dorky the `.whl` files from Gohlke are pre-compiled, so you don't *need* `vcvarsall.bat` at all.